# maven2 war overlay and eclipse WTP

Tags: java, maven-2, m2eclipse, eclipse-wtp

I have a maven war module which run eclipse WTP tomcat server like normal. Now i want to reuse that module artifact by using maven war overlay: i just create a new war project and include that module in project dependencies. The problem is now i cannot use eclipse "Run on server" anymore because i don't have any resource or config file (like web.xml) in the new project, everything is in the war dependencies but eclipse cannot resolve it.

Is there anyway to use a maven war overlay project run with eclipse ?

Thank you.

Comment: i think it is not supported yet: https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/MNGECLIPSE-599

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to have a war dependency on a war project, in other words doing a "war overlay", then it's not currently supported by m2eclipse 
Jer developped a plugin to implement this feature, you can give it a try : http://code.google.com/p/m2eclipse-wtp-ext/

Answer (score 1):

I've test this(to debug my first JASIG CAS server), and found it works in eclipse:
Using [Jetty Maven Plugin](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/jetty-maven-plugin.html) to run/debug war overlayed web apps.
Hope helpful~

Comment: The link Updated.

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same issue here. I agree with you that it's not supported yet (and has not been for almost 2 years!). There seems to be an alternative using q4e version 0.11.0+: http://wiki.eclipse.org/IAM_WTP_support which you can download from https://code.google.com/p/q4e/ or using the update site http://q4e.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/updatesite-iam/ . I'll give it a try and see whether and how it works (with m2eclipse at the same time active).

Comment: The combination of Eclipse, m2eclipse and war overlays (Maven) has been a big disappointment for me in the last 1.5 months. If I could choose again, I would not have used this technology as the parts don't work together well yet. Maybe better work with static resources next time ...

Comment: Well, it's now 2 years later and the combination of M2E and M2E-WTP is working very well.